# GET (googledrive-file) net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: html, video, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use a video I uploaded in googledrive, the link is an open acces to anyone as a viewer, in my HTML project but what I have back is an error. When i click on it it says i need to open it with an app, because they are 'analysing the video' since few hours.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vJgksW011ngQpyBV7xdrJid3X4cLFza_/view?usp=sharing
In the HTML I put:

```
<video controls autoplay width="320" height="240">
        <source src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vJgksW011ngQpyBV7xdrJid3X4cLFza_/view?usp=sharing" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

and it doesn't show nothing. In the console logs I got :

```
ERROR : GET https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vJgksW011ngQpyBV7xdrJid3X4cLFza_/view?usp=sharing net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

- Replace `/file/d/` with `/u/0/uc?id=`
- Replace ending `/view?usp=sharing` with `&export=download`

Input is:

- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vJgksW011ngQpyBV7xdrJid3X4cLFza_/view?usp=sharing

Output for usage in `<video>` tag:

- https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1vJgksW011ngQpyBV7xdrJid3X4cLFza_&export=download

Example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video id="background-video" autoplay loop muted poster="./assets/clouds_HP.jpg">
<source src="https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1vJgksW011ngQpyBV7xdrJid3X4cLFza_&export=download" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</body>

<script>

var vid = document.getElementById("background-video");
vid.addEventListener('click', function(evt) { handle_Click (evt) } );

function handle_Click (evt)
{
     //alert("clicked object ID is : " + evt.target.id);
     vid.muted = false;
}

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, the code works perfectly on my VScode, however on GitHub Pages it doesn't show up the video, neather a image. I was also wondering if it the same process for a font. I save a woof and woof2 and made the modify for the url as shown.

Comment: _"...On GitHub Pages it doesn't show up the video"_ Show me a link to the problem page.

Comment: I try to use the video as a background for the page: https://simone-me.github.io/my_test/

Comment: Try setting the first `<video>` line as: `<video id="background-video" muted autoplay loop poster="./assets/clouds_HP.jpg">` ...Basically you cannot **autoplay** a video with sound, so add a **muted** to the setup for playback. To have sound, the user must first click something on the page (_eg:_ click to reveal main page content (unhide something via CSS), this means they now can see main page with audio playing in video)

Comment: THANKS. I have been tring to fix the video issue since forever. really helpful. I still do not know how to put sound but for now it's fine. I may find some explanation online. The fact is that mute was on default but i took it out because on my local work as well with it. LOL

Comment: See if the edit helps you to get sound during playback. The quickest workaround is to have an option for users to click anywhere on the background (video) and thus enabling sound. So just add a `<script>` after your code for `<body>` where there is a listener for "click" on video object and then react with some function.